# How to align my font-awesome icon to the left of the navigation main menu item in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-awesome-5

I am trying to display my own font awesome 5 icons on my main navigation menu (WordPress) instead of using a plugin with 4.7 icons.

I thought I would start with my Home icon. So I went to my menu editor and switched the settings to display the CSS classes edit box.

Here is the site and you can see the Home button:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk

It is looking like this:

[image]

I set this as the class for the home button:

`fas fa-home`

And this is my custom CSS styling so far:

```
.fas::before {
    float: left;
    margin-right:.25em;
    margin-top: -.265em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 900;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I am trying to match the settings used on the other buttons so that the icon is to the left of the Home text but I can't get it to work. I have used the "Inspect Element" but can't get any further.

I saw this but the answer about using `fa-fw` seems to be for version 4.7?

I tried this:

```
.fas::before {
  float: left;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    margin-right:.25em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 900;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Things have improved but I still can't get the text "Home" on the right.

I also tried some of what it said here:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-icons-wordpress-menus/

But I can't get it right. No matter what I try, the Home link is below the icon. :(

Comment: It's working fine at my end. Please clear the caches and check again

Comment: @GovindSoni I had reverted back to using the plugin with 4.7 icon. But now I have changed it back to how it is described in my question. I look forward to any assistance so I can migrate to font-awesome 5 and stop needing any plugin for my menu icons.

Comment: Let me check now, please!

Comment: @GovindSoni I think I might be able to use this alternative plugin: https://github.com/cogdog/font-awesome-5-menus

Comment: as I can see now in home menu li hasn't <i /> tag but the remaining menu has <i /> tag. Could you please let me know if you did any custom thing for a specific menu like a home menu?

Comment: @GovindSoni I have installed a different plugin and removed my custom CSS and the home icon shows correctly. So I think I am OK and will try to roll this out on my other menu items.

Comment: @GovindSoni Using this additional plugin seems to get it OK now. I have deactivated the previous plugin.

Comment: Sounds good @Andrew

Comment: @GovindSoni The main issue I have now is the size of the icons. But I raised that here: https://github.com/cogdog/font-awesome-5-menus/issues/2